# Spring webflux , POST request data is getting truncated intermittently

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

1. Request Body sent via Post Method is getting truncated (sometimes) and hence not processed as required.
2. There is no memory exception thrown or seen in the application logs.
3. The same request is processed successfully after retrying

Spring boot Code Samples

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/updateRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public Mono<BookRecord> update(@RequestBody Payload e) {
    return bookService.sendRequest(e);
  }
```

```
public class RequestProcessor extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {

   
    private final ServerHttpRequest requestDecorator;

    public RequestProcessor(ServerHttpRequest requestDecorator) {
        super(requestDecorator);
        this.requestDecorator = requestDecorator;
   
    }



 @Override
public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    return super.getBody().doOnNext((dataBuffer) -> {
        try {
            Channels.newChannel(baos).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer());
            System.out.println(" Received payload " + IOUtils.toString(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException var11) {
            var11.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                baos.flush();
                baos.close();
            } catch (IOException var10) {
                var10.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
}
```

Sample logs...

The method iterates when the payload is truncated. See below

```
2023-01-20 18:33:53.059 | Severity=DEBUG | [16b38379-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8084 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62902] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver 
 Received payload {
    "data": "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
 Received payload {
    "data": "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"
}
```

Successful Request

```
2023-01-20 18:43:08.415 | Severity=DEBUG | [16b38379-3, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8084 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62902] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver 
 Received payload {
    "data": "EP2+t7DXkiKcdUeScGwck6kgWC2/Fzf5Q8oU2Jp2mQzAZm6SpB/Bjp0iDyB6HOuAafFi9X1vBkMqry+4TXEfTpjncHEbuGwiTD5IkujMA6/G4aVtbZ915eHMTcCdaCfqlg2v8X4GKZbKrnV7fmMLxEUruFItgfVZ+k6/U6MkqdluK6bXkXKaeopMTHQ2u8SgsDuYnqcx7Kh1313gOeHC/QuYDm4tdkXRnccs3CAcicQRMJJHQ3c2eR7Cbx1sY5KsgLazNz795iXjxStoJKoaY8AzwKwf6EpG2D9ndnCwTEKU18s73QJbgAXlB/XBVvSKJ7VYPx1z2sBPjCIbNByfOW6FoKnMdj4ux/dh/XrfQCuGsBg9yVTyGt2i4x5A5IqzzuD9qON0+5v8FXK78CiEFcIr0zlJqH3vdbRQKWwNuZdTB//9Ya6gZxxpsQ7aq9blx+0sgSPzK3p9tD+HvQ+vSr0v/N+nCXO/wVuaLBXpRkt2dzSrb3i1exRHOEFGL6Oefjl4vGdk0WUaNc6MSqxl1P+q7VBsJRQy7tsHj+SLucrUwmN+IykJlNkbXNn8jPxW7bLV65YFBXsQ5Ye5moYfs+SQqGDUrlofQ2R8yoAFmAZdOzrzjcdh8kdLjXCFtxrQRgqzo42HEm/wXCBIst/C1ThFTZkTaw5H4mqfVVqUQBl6UxqLvEH5YJYVR8mVJQ6QWNHoh2iKzweuV6JbHA4ususgMD03bDP/Qchd/0mz/CgrL1tuvpgX1UjWpwULBWzVFLt+bMWk314RSj9puCAAnTP2mEZdJ2a7fxz28y3Qmus/hPZprcABbJHAyCDQBsqmEfhw0fDdDdO9v0CmXXg2B93EILqIaks+x3HSqzUI1yvBo2RmCvHfX3iMe7wrbdWCXjUn1CRVKJsUjThXotfzqgYYdNQYo2CRApbHu3+VdaUc8KeOhVk86i62gQJXpHEgwSQgDmVE2CwpxGaT8tnbo2jIHxQ9W1iwCwwR8wuyyUb1dhZUYPC2/BzdloJaiYlkcMPktGO04j9VcfUIDXg90DKJ3wJpOY7heHzGM9R8Or7VMg9q3in1CKVlXplPAblpEHsMbjjh8CYx98fPuStsvFU0KBmVetOFcw45a9zEugEssi+8xuQKFIuzaJ1nQsAcScbNwSJ7GQM/1LgBLoX6gfMrux7cQg8nmc/0rLgZ4sKWT2d8LU9dHYp0+a2cEPaPsd0bv6swxBnh2mdoj89ZpAfE/SoCCV3OUQsqjqMWXTsCbefUiAPi88R5J9T4/FzKvLXz5VyKhA93hx5H+H6m4tGqihUCzl0VDsyqdxJZsrgnysUd0bFphnD5VUIwSwBNNSk5km0oU/1k+YKNcRTO/oZbcgDCqOohvp/4D6ZI9LCluVcKLUVxs1nZcr8m9ztDo4whdADP6uztZO13i4rfq3+N"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the request is divided into segments/chunks, each chunk will be an element in the Flux of DataBuffer.

You need to combine all the segments/chunks first if you want to read the complete request.

``

```java
Flux.from(DataBufferUtils.join(super.getBody())).map((dataBuffer) -> {

// your code


}
```

You can still use `.doOnNext()` instead of `.map()`, but it may mislead that the combined flux may still have multiple elements.